# Rest API for codenameone java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap

Tags: codenameone

For starters the Rest API is a lot easier to use than ConnectionRequest. However on the simulator it works well but on deploying the apk i get java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap. Why does it work on simulator and fail on APP and most important how do i fix this. Please see attached the code snippet

```
     List<Shift> shifts = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Object> result = (Map<String, Object>) Rest.get(new UrlManager().getShiftsAvailable())
            .acceptJson().getAsJsonMap().getResponseData();


    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> itr = result.entrySet().iterator();


    while (itr.hasNext()) {

        Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = itr.next();
        Log.p("Key: "+entry.getKey()+" Value: "+entry.getValue());
          Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> itr1 = (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>>) entry;

        LinkedHashMap<String,String> hm = (LinkedHashMap<String,String>) entry.getValue();

        Shift shift = new Shift(hm.get("id"), hm.get("createddate"),
                hm.get("start_time"), hm.get("end_time"),
                hm.get("driver_locations"), hm.get("shift_times"), hm.get("required_drivers"), hm.get("standby_drivers"), hm.get("check_in_minutes"));

        shifts.add(shift);

    }
```

Comment: I'm guessing the response from the server is different on the device and the cast you are getting doesn't work. Do you have a stack trace from the device to point you at the specific line that is failing? Notice you can print the content of the result map to the log as toString() to see how it differs.

Comment: Thanks I found out the problem...one of server variables had commas as in x = 5,6,7 which caused an arraylist cast error.